# Trying to call pl/sql function in python but receiving ORA-01858 error with to_date

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to call a pl/sql function using python. I am having issues using the 'to_date()' built in function.

Here is the "create_batch" function declaration

`create or replace function create_batch(
  p_batchnumber in VARCHAR,
  p_userid in VARCHAR,
  p_received_date in VARCHAR,
  p_workstation IN VARCHAR
) RETURN VARCHAR IS`

This is the line of coding I am trying to use to call this function.

`batch_id = cur.callfunc("create_batch", cx_Oracle.STRING, ['100001','test','to_date(\'05/15/2018\',\'MM/dd/yyyy\')','01'])`

This is the error message.

`File "test_oracle.py", line 7, in <module>
    batch_id = cur.callfunc("create_batch", cx_Oracle.STRING, ['100001','test','to_date(\'05/15/2018\',\'MM/dd/yyyy\')','01'])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "CFT.CREATE_BATCH", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1`

Any help that you could provide would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is your default settings for NLS_DATE_FORMAT at your cx_Oracle session level because that is the input date format you should give. If your session is set with NLS_DATE_FORMAT as MM/DD/YYYY, then you should send the date format with the following format.

```
batch_id = cur.callfunc("create_batch", cx_Oracle.STRING, ['100001','test','to_date("05/15/2018","MM/DD/YYYY")','01'])
```

You don't need to convert with to_date function for p_received_date as it is a VARCHAR input rather than a date input. So you can try with the following format assuming you are not setting the date format at the session level and you are using the default format:

```
batch_id = cur.callfunc("create_batch", cx_Oracle.STRING, ['100001','test','15-MAY-2018','01'])
```

Comment: I was able to just use '15-May-2018'. Thank you for your help!